# Validating Date (Leap year or not) before inserting into Database

Tags: c#, database, validation, date, leap-year

When I need to insert date into the database I need to check 2 things:

1. If this month has 31 days in case day 31 was selected
2. If February is selected, I need to check if it's a leap year in case the user selected 29

Currently I'm checking this using a long function filled with `if's` and `else's`.

Is there any method in `C#` that can check a date if it's valid or not before I insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime temp;
if (DateTime.TryParse(yourString, out temp))
{
    //valid, use temp to insert into DB.
}
else
{
    //not valid.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leap year validation

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 try
 {
  Console.Write("Please Enter the Year: ");
  int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("The year {0}, is a Leap Year", year);
       }
      else
       {
        Console.WriteLine("The year {0}, is not a Leap Year", year);
      }
  }
    catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
  Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

or simply you can use

```
if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
     {
         //your logic
     }
 else
    {
    }
```

Comment: There exists built in .net functionality for this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have three integers `years`, `months` and `days`, first check that `years` is between `1` and `9999`, then check that `months` is between `1` and `12`, and finally check that `days` is between `1` and [`DateTime.DaysInMonth(years, months)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx).

*Addition:* If it's for database storage, depending on the specific SQL column type, the range of valid years might be narrower, e.g. `1753` through `9999`. Anyway, the so-called "proleptic" Gregorian calendar is not historical correct, it's a kind of "extrapolation".

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value for February month with 28 or 29 depending on if that year is a leap year or not.

```
if (currentDate.Month == 2 && DateTime.IsLeapYear(currentDate.Year))
{
     //your logic to work on february month
}
else
{

}
```